Is ther any plan to show connectivity between If-then-else-endif sections?
Sure would like to see the if-then-else-endif sections connected by line id.
i.e.
if xxx;                  B01
endif;                   E01
Not sure what to try. Is there an extension or a setting to make this appear?
Sure would be helpful to see the connectivity between if/endif sections. I believe RDi has this?

If you're using SEU in 2024 please stop.
IBM's RDi or Visual Studio Code with the IBM i development pack are much better choices for writing code.
But fun fact, 20 or so years ago there was a product "RPG Alive" that would show indentations in SEU screens

fixed format

or free format


I wonder if this might be possible inside of VS Code. I will look into it!

With RDI, see IBM Rational - indentation available in Rational 9.6.0.6?
With Visual Studio Code for Ibm i, you have a native vertical line between indentation

Barry, I used RPG Alive! That's the thing I'm talking about. If you could get this worked up, that would be awesome!!

Thanks Charles and Dam. That's where I'm referencing this request from.
